# Ошибка в цикле проверки на уникальное значение

Tags: c++, циклы

Для практики делаю крестики-нолики, когда проверяю ячейку, была ли она уже использована возникает проблема, если несколько раз подряд ввести уже использованную ячейку, а после новую, то ячейка всё равно отобразится как повторяющаяся

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void CheckMove(int cellNumber, int* usedCells, int turn, int player);

void FieldDraw(char* upArr, char* divArr, char* midArr, char* lowArr)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << upArr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << divArr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << midArr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << divArr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << lowArr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void ChangePlayer(int &player)
{
    if (player == 1)
        player = 2;
    else
        player = 1;
}

void SymbChoice(char& FSymb, char& SSymb)
{
    cout << "Player 1 Choose your symbol" << endl;
    cin >> FSymb;
    cout << "Player 2 Choose your symbol" << endl;
    cin >> SSymb;
}

void AskMove(int player, int& cellNumber, int *usedCells, int turn)
{
    cin >> cellNumber;
    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin >> cellNumber;
    }

    CheckMove(cellNumber, usedCells, turn, player);
}

void CheckMove(int cellNumber, int *usedCells, int turn, int player)
{
    if (cellNumber < 1 || cellNumber > 9)
    {
        cout << "Please use 1 - 9" << endl;
        AskMove(player, cellNumber, usedCells, turn);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (cellNumber == usedCells[i])
        {
            cout << "This cell has been used, please choose another one" << endl;
            AskMove(player, cellNumber, usedCells, turn);
        }
    }
    usedCells[turn] = cellNumber;
}

void ChangeSymb(char FSymb, char SSymb, int cellNumber, int player, char* upArr, char* midArr, char* lowArr)
{
    char symb;

    if (player == 1)
        symb = FSymb;
    else
        symb = SSymb;

    switch (cellNumber)
    {
    case 1:
        upArr[0] = symb;
        break;
    case 2:
        upArr[4] = symb;
        break;
    case 3:
        upArr[8] = symb;
        break;
    case 4:
        midArr[0] = symb;
        break;
    case 5:
        midArr[4] = symb;
        break;
    case 6:
        midArr[8] = symb;
        break;
    case 7:
        lowArr[0] = symb;
        break;
    case 8:
        lowArr[4] = symb;
        break;
    case 9:
        lowArr[8] = symb;
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int player = 1;
    int turn = 0;
    char FPSymb = 'X';
    char SPSymb = '0';
    bool victory = false;
    int cellNumber = 0;
    int usedCells [9] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    char upArr[9] = { '1' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '2' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '3' };
    char divArr[9] = { '=' , '=' , '=' , '=' , '=' , '=' , '=' , '=' , '=' };
    char midArr[9] = { '4' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '5' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '6' };
    char lowArr[9] = { '7' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '8' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '9' };

    //SymbChoice(FPSymb, SPSymb);

    while (!victory)
    {
        FieldDraw(upArr, divArr,midArr, lowArr);
        if (player == 1)
            cout << "PLayer 1 Enter the cell number" << endl;
        else
            cout << "PLayer 2 Enter the cell number" << endl;
        AskMove(player, cellNumber, usedCells, turn);
        ChangeSymb(FPSymb, SPSymb, cellNumber, player, upArr, midArr, lowArr);
        ChangePlayer(player);
        turn++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну просто ошибка в сигнатурах функций.

```
void AskMove(, int& cellNumber, , )
void CheckMove(int cellNumber, , , )
```

И поскольку функции вызываются друг из друга, то получается крах.
Т.е. в AskMove передается ссылка на переменную из main, потом она в CheckMove передает по значению, а потом CheckMove передает в AskMove ссылку на локальную переменную внутри себя, а вовсе не ту, которая объявлена в main.
Но даже если это исправить, программа всё равно будет периодически рушиться.   Перекрестный вызов функций друг из друга - это плохо. Код не читаемый, логика не понятна и не отслеживается. Рано или поздно будет переполнение стэка (stackoverflow) из-за множественного вложенного вызова функций.
Стиль плохой.
Если функция называется AskMove, то она должна только спрашивать.
Если функция называется CheckMove, то она должна проверять возможность хода и просто возвращать да/нет.
Что-то вроде:

```cpp
    bool CheckMove(int cellNumber, int *usedCells, int turn, int player)
    {  
        bool State = true;
        if (cellNumber < 1 || cellNumber > 9)
        {
           cout << "Please use 1 - 9" << endl;
           State = false;
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (cellNumber == usedCells[i])
            {
                cout << "This cell has been used, please choose another one" << endl;
                State = false;
            }
        }
       return State;
    
    }
```

И тогда в main сделать цикл (спрашивать пока не будет введен корректный ход):

```cpp
   bool State = false;
   while(!State)
   {
     AskMove();
     State = CheckMove();
     if(State) usedCells[turn] = cellNumber;
   }
```

Таким образом - никаких перекрестных вызовов, линейное выполнение программы, логика работы понятна.
В дополнение - раз уж всё равно занята память под хранение признака заполненных ячеек usedCells, то проще проверять без цикла, в одну операцию - номер ячейки является индексом в массиве:
Установить, что ячейка занята:

```
usedCells[ cellNumber-1 ] = 1;
```

Проверка, что ячейка занята

```
if( usedCells[ cellNumber-1 ] ) 
{
}
```

И массив usedCells тогда можно сделать bool, a не int

Comment: ох, ну я намудрил, спасибо большое!